# Reading a CSV file without the full name

Tags: python, pandas, csv, import, import-from-csv

Very new to Python here. I am trying to read a file from a folder, but without knowing its full name.
For example `AAA_05212021.csv` is the file name located in `C:\test\`
AAA is the known part of the file name. The rest changes everyday.

I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\test\AAA*.csv')
```

.. but it doesn't seem to work.
Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) for this. Glob will return a list of files that match the pattern. Since, there is only one file that matches the pattern in the directory, you can get it with the index `0`:

```
from glob import glob
import pandas as pd

file = glob('C:\test\AAA*.csv')[0]
data = pd.read_csv(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should identify all of the possible files it could be:

```
import os

valid_files = []
for file in os.listdir('C:\test'):
    # Check that "AAA" is in the filename
    if "AAA" in file: 
        # Check that "AAA" is at the start of the filename
        if file.partition("AAA")[0] == "":
            valid_files.append(file)
```

Of course, if there are multiple files in the folder that follow that structure, you'll still need to pick one somehow, but that could be as simple as `files[0]` if you aren't picky.